# Chrome Content Script cannot attach listeners

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

As far as I know, you should be able to attach event listeners from within a content script. To bring it down to the bare essentials, I have this content script:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('img')) {
    alert('This will fire');
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('onclick', function() {
        alert('This will not fire');
    });
}
```

I even tried using a content script to inject a script element onto the page. But, the injected script also cannot attach event handlers.

For reference, here is a snippet of my manifest.json:

```
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "js": ["js/contentscript.js"],
    "all_frames": true
  }]
```

I went overboard with the permissions just to be positive that wasn't the issue.

Specifically, I would like to handle `img.onclick` and `window.onresize`. Where might I be going wrong?

---

EDIT:
Okay, so it works in regular content scripts now thanks to a stupid typo, but I can't get it to work when pages are loaded into iframes.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(){});
```

or

```
element.onclick = function(){};
```

instead of

```
element.addEventListener('onclick', function(){});
```

Comment: Ugh. Well that was a stupid mistake that caused a mis-diagnosed error. But, this still doesn't work when the page is loaded in an iframe.

Comment: @Chuck, are you using `window.frames`?

Comment: Nope. My idea was to have a content script run on _every page_ (which should include iframes, if I set it in the manifest). So, say I want an alert to pop up on `img.onclick`. It should work on pictures inside and outside of iframes.

Comment: [My guess](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76429). Even if it is not, then there's no way for me to help you debug this out

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of an obscure issue. Thanks for your help